# Select and Display from Multiple Tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

My homepage is www.respectmyplanet.org and I am writing on Codeigniter.  Disclaimer: I'm a financial analyst and just a hobbyist programmer and have no formal programming education.

To see an example of what I'm writing about below: if you click on any marker on my map at my homepage, you get an infowindow from an AJAX call that runs this method from my geo model:

```
public function get_well_infowindow ($permit) {
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mi_oil_well_info WHERE Permit_No = '%s' LIMIT 1 ",
    mysql_real_escape_string($permit));
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

If you look at the infowindow you will see a four digit number for operator and a four digit code for geologic formation.  All data is from the State of Michigan database provided by the MDEQ and I just shoved it into MySQL.

I want to make my infowindow say "Encana Gas Company" instead of "6450" from the 'big table' and I want it to say "Collingwood" for the Collingwood shale formation instead of CLGD from the 'big table'.  I have added two more tables from the State of Michigan that list all companies by code and all formations by code, but I don't know how to pull the data I need from multiple tables and make my infowindow use the more human readable information.

The other tables are real simple:

```
column1 - OpNo     column2 - OpName
6450               Encana Gas Company

column1-ObjForm    column2 - FormName
CLGD               Collingwood Shale
```

I echo out, currently, `$marker_info[0]->OpNo` and `$marker_info[0]->ObjForm` from the one call to the 'big table' and I want to echo out `$marker_info[0]->OpName` and `$marker_info[0]->FormName` but they come from those other tables and I don't have a clue how to do retrieve from multiple tables or echo this back out.

Can anyone help me: select everything from my "big table" like I do now which is working just fine, but swap the company code for company name and geologic formation code for long description of geologic formation and how to echo it back out?

Comment: Please, ask a concrete technological question, what you have tried and what doesn't work. You can't expect here to post task and get the solution programmed. The main idea: your question has to have potential value for the others.

Answer (score 0):

Do this by joining the tables in the SQL.  I didn't see in your question the name of the other two tables so I'll just refer to the first one as other_table_1.

Replace this:

```
SELECT * FROM mi_oil_well_info WHERE Permit_No = '%s' LIMIT 1
```

with this:

```
SELECT mi_oil_well_info.*, other_table_1.OpName
FROM mi_oil_well_info
LEFT JOIN other_table_1 ON mi_oil_well_info.OpNo=other_table_1.OpNo
WHERE Permit_No = '%s' LIMIT 1
```

You could also do this by running another select statement to look up the name given the Permit_No, but don't do that.  It will run much more quickly and efficiently if you join the tables and let the database look up the other fields.

More info on MySQL SELECT statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html